# Detecting Array

Tags: bios, array

I restarted my machine today and now it wont boot. 
it runs through the main bios, then it gives me a second message saying
Media rom bios 
detecting array...
and halts. any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Give us some more info. Model of machine or even better motherboard, etc etc. Does it say anything else except detecting array?

Comment: P5N-E SLI

it gets through the bios then it just flashes the detecting array... screen before completely going black and halting forever.

Comment: Raid 0? Sata or Pata(IDE) ?

Comment: I dont have a RAID set up at all. not sure what Pata(IDE) is

Comment: I checked my bios, all the raid settings are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The "detecting array" message may be a red-herring - it could just be the last thing that happens just before the failure.

First thing I would try from here is to open the case and make sure everything (power cables, data cables, cards) is plugged in securely. I've known cheap SATA data cables work lose and if the problem is somewhere around the drive controller that is a possibility. If you are not familiar with the insides of a PC: each drive should have two cables going to it, one from the power supply and on from the motherboard or other IO controller (a 40 line ribbon cable for PATA drives, a much less wide one for SATA).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the ribbon cable from the motherboard to the disk reader was causing the "detecting array" message.  Check your cables and you may do he your issue rather quickly.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This duplicates the information in David Spillett's answer.  The intention is that each answer contribute a solution that is substantively different from what has already been provided.  Just a heads up that it might attract downvotes for that reason.